# AS400 remote login using telnet

Tags: ibm-midrange

We frequently use telnet to "jump" between the 4 iSeries servers we support.
This requires us to type in the remote server name each time. I was thinking to come up with a simple cl program embedded within a command to bypass the typing effort required for specifying the remote server name. This part works fine.

Additionally, I've tried specifying correct values for the remote username and remote password parameters. This simply doesn't bypass the sign on screen.

I've researched and ensured that qrmtsign system value is set to "same profile".
The telnet works fine and the sign on screen comes up. But what am I missing here that is required to bypass the sign on screen as well?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the built-in telnet command has no option to forward authentication: Telnet in OS/400 doesn't seem to be the right tool, as it seems to be a compatibility tool to log in to ASCII telnet devices. I'd opt to build a native SNA APPN overlay network over IP and use the native 5250 passthrough service.

To do that, decide one machine to be the Network Node (knowing about all other machines in the SNA network), create a SNA Controller description (crtctlappc type *HPRIP) on each machine pointing to the IP of the NN and setting all other nodes to End Node (see dspneta/chgneta). There you can also easily change the SNA node names from the machines. If you have QAUTOCFG, QAUTORMT and QAUTOVRT system values (at least temporarily) set to 1, you can vary on the controller descriptions and everything else will be done automatically. Hint: SNA sometimes needs a lot of time to settle to a stable state. Give it a couple of minutes after doing changes if stuff doesn't work.

You can test connectivity by using aping (appc ping) to the SNA node names. You can use wrkappnsts to check SNA network status.

And instead of using telnet, you now use strpasthr (on the originating host) and endpasthr (on the host where you signed in and want to sign out). See Parameters of strpasthr with F4 for details.